# Loop with conditions in R programming

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements, apply

I would like to compare the previous row value whether it is same as the current one (for more than 1 variables and also using list of values). In this case how do I perform write code. I read 'apply' functions can be used.

I searched this topic here before posting this question found somewhat similar but unable to find the exact one. I'm quite new to R.

Here is my sample table: (Flag needs to be done based on conditions)

```
Ticket No   V1  V2  Flag
Tkt10256    1   X   0
Tkt10257    1   aa  0
Tkt10257    2   bb  1
Tkt10257    3   x   0
Tkt10260    1   cc  0
Tkt10260    2   aa  1
Tkt10262    3   bb  0
```

I have to **Flag** based on the below conditions (if all the conditions are satisfied then mark as 1)

1. Variable 2 should be the following one of 4 names (aa, bb, cc, dd)
2. Variable 1 should be the different from previous row
3. Ticket number has to be the same as previous row

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: V1 is not the same on rows 3 and 4 but you flagged it as such. And on row 4 you have `x` in V2 and you also flagged it.  These should not be 1, according to your conditions. Please correct this

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion there Richard. Condition 2 is v1 should be the different from previous row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach without looping:

```
indx1 <- with(df, V2 %in% paste0(letters[1:4], letters[1:4]) )
indx2 <- with(df, c(TRUE,V1[-1]!=V1[-length(V1)]))
indx3 <- with(df, c(FALSE,Ticket.No[-1]==Ticket.No[-nrow(df)]))

df$Flag <- (indx1 & indx2 & indx3)+0
df$Flag
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Ticket.No = c("Tkt10256", "Tkt10257", "Tkt10257", 
"Tkt10257", "Tkt10260", "Tkt10260", "Tkt10262"), V1 = c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), V2 = c("X", "aa", "bb", "x", "cc", "aa", 
"bb"), Flag = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Ticket.No", 
"V1", "V2", "Flag"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Nice.  I was thinking of using `within` with an `ifelse` inside.

Comment: @Richard Scriven Thanks. Yes, that is an option

Comment: It worked well Akrun, Thanks a lot ! I'm also trying this using loop or apply function as that would be a good learning for me.

Comment: @Mathan For bigger dataset, the looping can be slow.  I would use a vectorized option.  I guess rnso already gave you an option using `for` loop

Answer (score 2):

One more:

Check this on your larger data. I'm not exactly sure if `duplicated` is the right function to use there.  If the numbers in the `TicketNo` column are increasing (i.e. the Xs in TktXXXXX), then it should work fine.

```
> dat2 <- dat[dat$V2 %in% c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"),]
> rn <- rownames(dat2)[duplicated(dat2[[1]]) & !c(FALSE, diff(dat2[[2]]) == 0)]
> dat$Flag <- (rownames(dat) %in% rn)+0
> dat
#   TicketNo V1 V2 Flag
# 1 Tkt10256  1  X    0
# 2 Tkt10257  1 aa    0
# 3 Tkt10257  2 bb    1
# 4 Tkt10257  3  x    0
# 5 Tkt10260  1 cc    0
# 6 Tkt10260  2 aa    1
# 7 Tkt10262  3 bb    0
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on @Akrun's answer:

```
with(df, 
  V2 %in% c("aa","bb","cc","dd") &  
  c(FALSE,diff(V1) != 0) &
  c(FALSE,head(Ticket.No, -1)) == Ticket.No
) + 0

#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(ddf)){
   ddf$Flag[i] = ifelse(  ddf$V2[i] %in% c('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd') 
           && ddf$V1[i] != ddf$V1[(i-1)] 
           &&  ddf$TicketNo[i] == ddf$TicketNo[(i-1)]
         ,1,0)
 }
ddf
  TicketNo V1 V2 Flag
1 Tkt10256  1  X    0
2 Tkt10257  1 aa    0
3 Tkt10257  2 bb    1
4 Tkt10257  3  x    0
5 Tkt10260  1 cc    0
6 Tkt10260  2 aa    1
7 Tkt10262  3 bb    0
```